# Twig Runtime Error on settings/general (value: system.name)

Tags: control-panel, error

When I go to settings/general in the CP i get this Twig Runtime Error.  Does anoyone here know what to do to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Which version of Craft are you on?

Comment: Version 3.6.11.1

Comment: I tried this but now I can't access the Craft-installation at all... [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR3ja.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR3ja.png) [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAmqG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAmqG.png)

Comment: Do you have a backup of the database? Is this a new project or an exisiting? The error log mentions a missing project name usually thats set when running `./craft setup` 

Answer (score 1):

You might need to fix this manually.

Open your `config/project/project.yaml` and make sure that the `system` object has all the following keys in there (you seem to be missing `name`):

```
system:
  edition: pro
  live: true
  name: Site Name
  retryDuration: null
  schemaVersion: 3.6.6
  timeZone: Europe/Paris
```

Once you have done that, run `./craft project-config/apply` and the error should go.

Note that the `schemaVersion` is for Craft `3.6.11.1`.

Comment: OBS - this broke my site! se images below.

Comment: You need to replace the `xxx` with actual values!! See above